# MEAN Stack http PUT request issue

Tags: node.js, angular, express, crud, mean-stack

i'm pretty new in MEAN STACK.

I make my API REST under Nodejs Express and mongoodb.
I use Angular 14 as client.

I made a little project where user can register / login / display user informations.
Now i'd like to add an update functionality. A simple form where user can update his name or his role. I'm stuck at this point and i'd like to know why my code don't work and how can i fix this. It's been 2 days i'm on it, that's why i'm there to have some informations.

This is my config.json

```
{
"development": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/PangolinDB",
    "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
    "JWT_EXP": "10m"
},
"production": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://xxxxx/DB_Name",
    "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
    "JWT_EXP": "2m"
 }
}
```

user.controller.js

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const passport = require('passport');
 const _ = require('lodash');
 const { rest } = require('lodash');
 const User = mongoose.model('User');
 // updated crud code



ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; //catch collection Id
// end updated crud code



 module.exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
//console.log('inside register function');
var user = new User();
user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.password = req.body.password;
user.role = req.body.role;
user.followers = req.body.followers;
user.following = req.body.following;
user.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err)
        res.send(doc);
    else {
        if (err.code = 1100)
            res.status(422).send(['L\'adresse email existe déja.']);
            else
                return next(err);
    } 

});
 }

 module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
 //call for passport authentication
 passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    //error from passport middleware
    if (err) return res.status(404).json(err);
    //registered user
    else if(user) return res.status(200).json({ "token" : user.generateJwt() });
    //unknow user or wrong password
    else return res.status(401).json(info);
})(req,res);
 }

  module.exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req._id },
    (err, user) => {
        if (!user)
        return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'User record not found'});
        else
         return res.status(200).json({ status: true, user: _.pick(user,['fullName',         

      'email', 'role', 'friends','followers','following']) });


    })
  }

module.exports.getAllUser = async (req, res) => {
const users = await User.find().select('-password');
res.status(200).json(users);
 };

module.exports.userInfo = (req, res) => {
if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

User.findById(req.params.id, (err,docs) => {
if(!err) res.send(docs);
else console.log('ID unknown ; ' . err);
}) .select('-password');

};

 module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

try {
 await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: req.params.id},
  {
    $set: {
      role : req.body.role
    },
  },
  { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true},
 )
  .then((docs) => res.send(docs))
  .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({ message: err }));

 } catch (err){
return res.status(500).json({ message: err});
}
}

module.exports.deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
 return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id)

try {
  await User.remove({_id: req.params.id}).exec();
res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully deleted. "});
} catch (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
 }

  module.exports.follow = async (req, res) => {
 /* if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id) || !ObjectId.isValid(req.params.idToFollow))
 return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id) */

try {
// add to the follower list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id, // id wanted to being followed
  { $addToSet: { following: req.body.idToFollow } }, // id being followed
  { new : true, upsert: true },
  
);
// add to following list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.idToFollow,
  { $addToSet: { followers: req.params.id}},
  { new: true, upsert: true },
)
return res.status(201).json(docs);

 }catch (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
};

module.exports.unfollow = async (req, res) => {
   /* if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id) || !ObjectId.isValid(req.params.idToFollow))
return res.status(400).send('ID unknown :' + req.params.id) */

try {
// add to the follower list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id, // id wanted to being followed
  { $pull: { following: req.body.idToUnFollow } }, // id being followed
  { new : true, upsert: true },
  
);
// add to following list
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.idToUnFollow,
  { $pull: { followers: req.params.id}},
  { new: true, upsert: true },
)
return res.status(201).json(docs);

 }catch (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
};
```

user.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Full name can\'t be empty'
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Email can\'t be empty',
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Password can\'t be empty',
    minlength: [4, 'Password must be atleast 4 character long']
},
role: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Role can\'t be empty',
},
followers: {
    type: String,
},
following: {
    type: String,
},

saltSecret: String
});



// Custom validation for email
userSchema.path('email').validate((val) => {
emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\. 
 [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return emailRegex.test(val);
}, 'Invalid e-mail.');

// Events encrypt password
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        this.password = hash;
        this.saltSecret = salt;
        next();
    });
});
});


// Methods verify password
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function (password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function () {
return jwt.sign({ _id: this._id},
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
{
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXP
});
}



mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ctrlUser = require('../controllers/user.controller');

const jwtHelper = require('../config/jwtHelper');

//auth
router.post('/register', ctrlUser.register,);
router.post('/authenticate',ctrlUser.authenticate);


// user display 
router.get('/userProfile',jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, ctrlUser.userProfile);
router.get('/list', ctrlUser.getAllUser);
router.get('/user/:id', ctrlUser.userInfo);
router.put("/user/:id",ctrlUser.updateUser);
router.delete("/user/:id",ctrlUser.deleteUser);

//follow
router.patch('/user/follow/:id', ctrlUser.follow);
router.patch('/user/unfollow/:id', ctrlUser.unfollow);



module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
require('./config/config');
require('./models/db');
require('./config/passportConfig');
require('./routes/index.router')

const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');

 //updated code

// end updtated code


const rtsIndex = require('./routes/index.router');
var app = express();
// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/api', rtsIndex);


//
/* app.use('api',routeList); */
//

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
    var valErrors = [];
    Object.keys(err.errors).forEach(key => valErrors.push(err.errors[key].message));
    res.status(422).send(valErrors)
}
else{
    console.log(err);
}
});

// start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at port :   

${process.env.PORT}`));




user.service.ts (angular 14)





import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Observable, ObservableInput, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


 @Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
selectedUser: User = {
id:'',
fullName: '',
email: '',
password: '',
role:'',
friends:'',
followers:'',
following:'',
};

noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True'}) };
errorMgmt: (err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<any>;
HttpHeaders: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

//httpMethods

//user form

//register ()
postUser(user: User){
return this.http.post( environment.apiBaseUrl+'/register',user,this.noAuthHeader);
}
//login ()
login(authCredentials: any){
  return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/authenticate', authCredentials,   

 this.noAuthHeader);
}

//user profile
//user infos
getUserProfile(){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/userProfile');
} // need jwt in header

getOne(){
  const token = this.getToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization ':'bearer'+ token});
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl+'/userProfile',{headers});
}

updateUser(_id: any, value: any){
  return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseUrl + `/user/${_id}`, value);
}

edit(_id: any, data: any){
  return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseUrl + `/user/${_id}`, data);
}

//get all users
getAllUsers(){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/list');
}

//Helper Methods

setToken(token: string) {

  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}

getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

deleteToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
}

getUserPayload(){
  var token = this.getToken();
  if (token) {
    var getUserPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
    return JSON.parse(getUserPayload);
  }
  else
  return null;
}

isLoggedIn() {
  var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
  if (userPayload)
    return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
  else
    return false;
}

// Error
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
let errorMessage = '';
if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Handle client error
  errorMessage = error.error.message;
} else {
  // Handle server error
  errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
}
console.log(errorMessage);
return throwError(() => {
  errorMessage;
});
}



}
```

edit.component.ts

```
import { UserService } from './../shared/user.service';
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validator, Validators, SelectControlValueAccessor,  

FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit',
templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})

/* export class EditComponent implements OnInit{

editUsr = new FormGroup({
fullName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  role: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});

loading: boolean =true;
id: any;

constructor (
private userService : UserService,
private activateRoute : ActivatedRoute,
private route: Router
){}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.activateRoute.params.subscribe((data: any) =>{
  this.id = data['id'];
  this.userService.getOne(this.id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
    if (res.user != undefined){
      this.editUsr.get('fullName')?.setValue(res.user.fullName);
      this.editUsr.get('email')?.setValue(res.user.email);
      this.editUsr.get('role')?.setValue(res.user.role);
    }
  });
  this.loading = false;
});
  
}

addUser(){
const data: any = {
  fullName : this.editUsr.get('fullName')?.value,
  email : this.editUsr.get('email')?.value,
  role: this.editUsr.get('role')?.value
}

this.userService.edit(this.id, data).subscribe(()=>this.route.navigateByUrl('edit'));
}
}

*/

export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

getId:any;
updateForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
private router: Router,
private ngZone: NgZone,
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private UserService: UserService
) { 
this.getId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.UserService.getOne().subscribe(res=>{
  this.updateForm.patchValue({
    fullName: res['fullName'],
    email: res['email'],
    role: res['role']
  });
});
this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  fullName:[''],
  email:[''],
  role:[''],
 })

}
ngOnInit(): void {}
onUpdate(): any{
this.UserService.updateUser(this.getId, this.updateForm.value).subscribe(()=>{
  console.log('mise à jouer effectuée avec succès')
  this.ngZone.run(()=> this.router.navigateByUrl('/userprofile'))
},(err)=> {
  console.log(err);
});
}

}
```

edit.component.html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">
       <h2>Edit User</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullName">FullName</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="fullName" id="fullName" >
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email" id="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">Role</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="role" id="role">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" >Enregistrer</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" [routerLink]="['/userprofile']"   

   type="submit">Retour</button>
  </div>

 </form>
</div>
</div>


<p>edit works!</p>
```

environment.ts

```
// This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

export const environment = {
production: false,
apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
};

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative 

impact
* on performance if an error is thrown.
*/
// import 'zone.js/plugins/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

routes.ts

```
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
 import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { UserComponent } from "./user/user.component";
import { SignUpComponent } from "./sign-up/sign-up.component";
import { SignInComponent } from "./user/sign-in/sign-in.component";
import { UserProfileComponent } from "./user-profile/user-profile.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./auth/auth.guard";

 export const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
 {path:'edit', component:EditComponent},
 {
path: 'signup', component: UserComponent,
children: [{ path:'', component: SignUpComponent}]
},
{
path: 'login', component: UserComponent,
children: [{ path:'', component: SignInComponent}]
},
{
 path: 'userprofile', component: UserProfileComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]
},
{
 path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'
 }
];
```

thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: What exactly is the question? I would narrow things down by targeting the front and the backend individually - try to hit your update endpoint from outside the Angular app. Does it behave as expected? What if you run your Angular app and comment out the portion that makes the api call. How does it behave?

Comment: my back-end work properly. All my crud opérations are ok. But my front-end don't. When i'm logged in, i want to click on my edit button to change my name, role.. but i'm stuck there. My API REST route `router.put("/user/:id",ctrlUser.updateUser);`  don't work when i make the HTTP PUT request. I

Comment: How so? Try to be more specific. Do you get error messages? Do you not get a response at all? Is the request made? You'll get answers much faster if you can clearly outline what your issue is and what you've tried.

Comment: When i log in my account, i have two option : logout / edit. When i click on edit button i have a simple form where i can change my fullnam / email / role. But when i want to save my change i have`PUT` `source:HTTP` `400 Bad Request` `host : localhost:3000`  `filename:/api/user/undefined`. My id is unknown : `ID unknown: undefined`. I don't know how to catch my user id. Everything work when i log in

Comment: i found the issue.  On my API REST i can only change the role, not the fullname and email, that's why this couldn't work with angular. I asked to change to many fields.